# How to serialize a Graph-like AVL tree to disk?

Tags: c, algorithm, serialization, tree

I know it sounds weird but this is it. I have a data structure which is basically a modified AVL tree. Each node of the the structure has a left child and a right child. These core pointers (left & right) will be used to link all data nodes together and to keep the data structure balanced (AVL rotations) to improve searching. But those are not the only pointers in the structure, there are others that can point to any random node in the tree (Which creates the graph-like analogy).
The tree is built at runtime through user interaction (CLI). The user is also responsible for creating all the different links between the nodes.
An example of such a data structure could be (Didn't start coding yet, it's only prototyping):

```
struct node {
    struct node *left; 
    struct node *right 
    struct node *links[NUM]; // Points to any random node in the tree.
    /* Probably many other fields here that could be either pointers 
       or other data types */
}
```

Now, everything is in RAM. Once the user wants to exit, all the data nodes (The whole tree) should be saved to a file in binary mode (For later reloading, so one must take this in consideration).
It's, basically, easy to save the AVL tree using one the recursive tree traversal algorithms (In this case the question is a duplicate because solutions already exist in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337868/want-to-save-binary-tree-to-disk-for-20-questions-game)). But, in my case, i have to preserve all the arbitrarily created links between the nodes.
What could be the most efficient way in time & space ?

Comment: I suggest you try to find some kind of serialization-library which can handle arbitrary data including pointers. Attempting to write serialization for complex data-structures like this, all by yourself, is usually a lot of work and is prone to very bad bugs.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is one good proposition, never thought about that, LOL. Do you know any open source C libs for that ?

Answer (score 1):

You could dump your data structure as is (including the pointer values) and, in the binary blob of each node, also add its address. When reloading the data structure you will dynamically allocate your nodes and store their new addresses in a hash table which access keys are the old addresses. In a final pass you will parse your hash table sequentially (not using the old addresses as keys), retrieve the new address of each node, and update its pointer fields from old addresses to new addresses using again your hash table as a translation table (with the old addresses as access keys).

Comment: I have already thought about the same idea but thinking like it's a Mapping table. A hash table is probably extremely efficient. The problem is that the approach is really bad in space because the tree can get really really huge, like 10^7 nodes. In this case, the needed table could be really big. 8 bytes entries will result in 80 MB table maintained in main memory. What do you think about that ?

Comment: I think we can implement some kind of userspace paging but, well, this looks really like a lot of work.

Comment: What kind of hardware do you have? 80 MB is not that big nowadays where the lightest laptop has 4GB. If you really care about memory footprint you should probably consider the solution proposed by comingstorm. 32 bits indexes instead of 64 bits pointers will already save a lot on your data structure itself.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a unique index number for each node, and use it to serialize the links.

This will likely take two traversal passes -- one to set the index number, and one to do the serialization.  Add an integer field to your `node` to hold the index number; you shouldn't need any other memory overhead.

Alternately, if you manage your tree nodes by storing them in an array or `std::vector`, you will already have an index number handy, and you won't need an additional index field.  Also, you can store all your links as indices instead of pointers, so you can just serialize your container as-is.

Comment: Well, i have already thought of it. it's probably a nice, simple way to save the nodes to the disk. The problem here is the reloading process because i think you have to make a lot of I/O to get every link resolved. What do you think ?

Comment: Maybe we can implement some kind of a mapping table (A hash table) as the other answer of @Renaud Pacalet suggests but there's some memory overhead.

Comment: If your links are all `std::vector`-style indices, you don't need to convert them back to pointers.  If not, regenerating link pointers is also a 2-pass operation:  e.g., when de-serializing to memory, save pointers to the newly-allocated nodes in an `std::vector`-style array.  Afterwards, converting each link index to a pointer is just an array lookup!